# c++ error: passing ‘const std::vector<Node>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, object, compilation, iterator, set

I have this error when i try to insert an object into a set of a `stl vector`, `Node` is a class that i have created. ¿Could you explain to me how to solve this error?

Code:

```
void car::expandnode(Node& current_node,std::set<vector<Node> >& closed_list,grid& map){

    int c_a = current_node.get_x();
    int c_b= current_node.get_y();

    if((map.get(c_a,++c_b))!=1){

        point p(c_a,++c_b);
       Node ns(p,costtan);

       costtan= 1+ heuristic1(ns); // cost to arrive node

       if(std::find((*closed_list.end()).begin(),(*closed_list.end()).end(),ns)==((*closed_list.end()).end()))
                closed_list.end()->push_back(ns); //error

     }


float car::heuristic1(Nodo& successor){
        int c1= successor.get_x();
        int c2= successor.get_y();
        float result = sqrt(pow((c1-destination_point_.get_x()),2) + pow((c2-destination_point_.get_y()),2));

        return resultado;

    }
```

Error:

```
 error: passing ‘const std::vector<Node>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                 closed_list.end()->push_back(ns);
```

Thanks

**EDIT1:**

I am implementing the A star algorithm, so in the function expandnode if a successor is not an obstacle (`!=1`), i insert it in the `set` of `vector`, this set contains the successors nodes of each node, i added more code to the question to clarify my doubt

Because i am calling `expandnode()` from other function (main A-star function), i need to insert the succesors of each node on the last vector of the `set`, i use `.end()` for that purpose, because initially each vector have one node, once made the call to `expandnode()` this vector have the node and its successors

Comment: `closed_list.end()->push_back(ns);` -- What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that line of code?  Whatever it is, that code doesn't do it.

Comment: Dereferencing `.end()` is undefined behavior as it only acts as a placeholder. It points one past the last element.

Comment: `*closed_list.end()` -- You do this in multiple places.  This is completely wrong (dereferencing the end() iterator).  So you should state what you're trying to do with these lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited the question

Comment: @AER The last element of a set is [closed_list.rbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin).  Dereferencing `end()` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closed_list` is a `std::set`.  The objects stored in a `set` are const objects, since modifying them can potentially change how the modified object sorts in relation to the other objects in the `set`.

When you dereference an iterator of a `set`, the reference you get is a `const &`.  When you then try calling `push_back` on that object, the compiler generates an error because `push_back` cannot be called on a `const` object.

Another problem with the code is that the `end` iterator of any standard container is not dereferencable, and doing so as you do results in Undefined Behavior.  Perhaps you meant to use `back()` instead, which returns a reference to the last item in the container?

This still won't address the problem of modifying an object in a set.  To do that, you need to erase the object from the set, modify it, then reinsert the modified object.

Comment: [rbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin) gets the iterator to the last element of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is that all elements in a `set` are ordered by operator `<` by default. You may want to override it.